# Как создать статический класс в C++?

Tags: c++, классы

Я только начал изучать C++, и хотел сделать статический класс чтобы к его методам можно было обратиться, не создавая объект smartRandom:

smartRandom.h:

```
namespace sr
{
    class smartRandom
    {
    public:
        static void init();
        static int random(int from, int to);

    };
};
```

smartRandom.cpp:

```
namespace sr
{
    class smartRandom
    {
        static void init()
        {
            srand(time(NULL));
        }

        static int random(int from, int to)
        {
            return from + rand() % (to - from + 1);
        }
    };
}
```

В программе вызываю класс так:

```
sr::smartRandom::random(3, 10);
```

Но мне выходит 4 ошибки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я попробовал исправить но появилось это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Определения делаются с помощью операции разрешения контекста, а Вы переопределяете class smartRandom

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup Спасибо! Но можете ли вы привести пример как это исправить? Я просто без понятия.

Comment: Не по теме - но Если хотите смарт рандом на Окошках, КриптоАпи Вам в руки.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы переопределяете class smartRandom в smartRandom.cpp. Определения методов и статических функций класса осуществляются с помощью операции разрешения контекста. Вот так:

smartRandom.h

```
#ifndef SMART_RANDOM_H_
#define SMART_RANDOM_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

namespace sr
{
    class smartRandom
    {
    public:
        static void init();
        static int random(int from, int to);
    };
};

#endif
```

smartRandom.cpp

```
#include "smartRandom.h"

namespace sr
{
    void smartRandom::init()
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
    }

    int smartRandom::random(int from, int to)
    {
        return from + rand() % (to - from + 1);
    }
}
```

Файл, где у Вас main

```
#include "smartRandom.h"

int main()
{
    sr::smartRandom::random(3, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может это проблема с компилятором, но мне пишет ```
Ошибка LNK2005 "public: static int __cdecl sr::smartRandom::random(int,int)" (?random@smartRandom@sr@@SAHHH@Z) уже определен в smartRandom.obj Обучение по книжке C:\Users\Users\source\repos\Обучение по книжке\Обучение по книжке\Обучение по книжке.obj 1```

Comment: @Lenator удалите определения методов в классе. Оставьте только прототипы. Я обновил ответ.

Comment: очень много ошибок :( "использование неопределённого типа sr:smartRandom" таких 3 ошибки

Comment: @Lenator нужно два двоеточия

Comment: Исправил описание. Переписал прям как у вас

Comment: @Lenator Отредактировал ответ. Работает железно))) Вы как компилируете?

Comment: в smartRandom.cpp  уже есть  namespace sr . Достаточно написать using sr;

Comment: @NotBjarneStroustrup всё заработало) спасибо) я просто случайно написал ещё #include "smartRandom.cpp"